# Algorithm for planning a rendezvous between two spaceships

Tags: physics, kinematics

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm for setting up a rendezvous between two spaceships.

There is no gravity or drag. Both spaceships have a position and a velocity at the start. Spaceship B continues on its course with no acceleration, so spaceship A needs to accelerate to close the distance between them and then match velocities when it arrives at the position of spaceship B.

The spaceship can instantly change its direction of thrust, but can only use maximum acceleration or no acceleration at all. I also want a limit on the velocity difference between the spaceships during the maneuver.

I would like the output to be in the form of a number of trajectory legs, i.e: leg1: accelerate direction x for t1 seconds, 
leg2: coast for t2 seconds, 
leg3: accelerate direction y for t3 seconds.

I don't need an optimal solution, but I would like it to "look right".

I tried to make an impulse to equalize the velocities and add it to an impulse for moving towards spaceship B, but even though spaceship A ends up with the correct velocity, it fails to reach the targets position. I've tried the impulses by themselves and they seem to perform as expected, so I'm guessing it's the way I'm adding them together that is the problem. I don't know if I am implementing it incorrectly or if this approach simply won't work. I'm hoping someone with stronger math and physics skills can enlighten me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// var velocityAdjustmentTime =  (int)Math.Sqrt(2 * velocityDelta.Length / tp.Acceleration);
            var velocityAdjustmentTime = (int)(velocityDelta.Length / tp.Acceleration);

            var velocityAdjustVector = velocityDelta;
            velocityAdjustVector.Normalize();
            velocityAdjustVector *= tp.Acceleration;

            var targetAccelerationDisplacement = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0); // TODO: Replace this with proper values.

            Vector3D newPosition;
            Vector3D newVelocity;
            Vector3D targetNewPosition;

            // Check if the formation and the target already have a paralell course with the same velocity.
            if (velocityAdjustmentTime > 0)
            {
                // If not, calculate the position and velocity after the velocity has been aligned.
                newPosition = tp.StartPosition + (tp.StartVelocity * velocityAdjustmentTime) + ((velocityAdjustVector * velocityAdjustmentTime * velocityAdjustmentTime) / 2);
                newVelocity = tp.StartVelocity + velocityAdjustVector * velocityAdjustmentTime;
                targetNewPosition = tp.TargetStartPosition + (tp.TargetStartVelocity * velocityAdjustmentTime) + targetAccelerationDisplacement;
            }

            else
            {
                // Else, new and old is the same.
                newPosition = tp.StartPosition;
                newVelocity = tp.StartVelocity;
                targetNewPosition = tp.TargetStartPosition;
            }

            // Get the new direction from the position after velocity change.
            var newDirection = targetNewPosition - newPosition;


            // Changing this value moves the end position closer to the target. Thought it would be newdirection length, but then it doesn't reach the target.
            var length = newDirection.Length;

            // I don't think this value matters.
            var speed = (int)(cruiseSpeed);

            var legTimes = CalculateAccIdleDecLegs(tp.Acceleration, length, speed);

            // Sets how much of the velocity change happens on the acceleration or deceleration legs.
            var velFactorAcc = 1;
            var velFactorDec = 1 - velFactorAcc;

            // Make the acceleration vector.
            accelerationVector = newDirection;
            accelerationVector.Normalize();
            accelerationVector *= legTimes[0] * tp.Acceleration;

            accelerationVector += velocityDelta * velFactorAcc;



            accelerationTime = (int)(accelerationVector.Length / tp.Acceleration);

            accelerationVector.Normalize();
            accelerationVector *= tp.Acceleration;


            // Make the acceleration order.
            accelerationLeg.Acceleration = accelerationVector;
            accelerationLeg.Duration = accelerationTime;

            // Make the deceleration vector.
            decelerationVector = newDirection;
            decelerationVector.Negate();
            decelerationVector.Normalize();
            decelerationVector *= legTimes[2] * tp.Acceleration;

            decelerationVector += velocityDelta * velFactorDec;

            decelerationTime = (int)(decelerationVector.Length / tp.Acceleration);

            decelerationVector.Normalize();
            decelerationVector *= tp.Acceleration;

            // And deceleration order.
            decelerationLeg.Acceleration = decelerationVector;
            decelerationLeg.Duration = decelerationTime;

            // Add the orders to the list.
            trajectory.Add(accelerationLeg);

            // Check if there is an idle leg in the middle...
            if (legTimes[1] > 0)
            {
                // ... if so, make the order and add it to the list.
                idleLeg.Duration = legTimes[1];

                trajectory.Add(idleLeg);
            }

            // Add the deceleration order.
            trajectory.Add(decelerationLeg);
```

And the function for calculating the approach legs:

```
private static int[] CalculateAccIdleDecLegs(double acceleration, double distance, int cruiseSpeed)
    {
        int[] legDurations = new int[3];
        int accelerationTime;
        int idleTime;
        int decelerationTime;

        // Calculate the max speed it's possible to accelerate before deceleration needs to begin.
        var topSpeed = Math.Sqrt(acceleration * distance);

        // If the cruise speed is higher than or equal to the possible top speed, the formation should accelerate to top speed and then decelerate.
        if (cruiseSpeed >= topSpeed)
        {
            // Get the time to accelerate to the max velocity.
            accelerationTime = (int)((topSpeed) / acceleration);

            // Idle time is zero.
            idleTime = 0;

            // Get the deceleration time.
            decelerationTime = (int)(topSpeed / acceleration);
        }

        // Else, the formation should accelerate to max velocity and then coast until it starts decelerating.
        else
        {
            // Find the acceleration time.
            accelerationTime = (int)((cruiseSpeed) / acceleration);

            // Get the deceleration time.
            decelerationTime = (int)(cruiseSpeed / acceleration);

            // Calculate the distance traveled while accelerating.
            var accelerationDistance = 0.5 * acceleration * accelerationTime * accelerationTime;

            // Calculate the distance traveled while decelerating.
            var decelerationDistance = 0.5 * acceleration * decelerationTime * decelerationTime;

            // Add them together.
            var thrustDistance = accelerationDistance + decelerationDistance;

            // Find the idle distance.
            var idleDistance = distance - thrustDistance;

            // And the time to idle.
            idleTime = (int)(idleDistance / cruiseSpeed);
        }

        legDurations[0] = accelerationTime;
        legDurations[1] = idleTime;
        legDurations[2] = decelerationTime;

        return legDurations;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW VERSION:**

Assume you have the initial positions and velocities `xA0, vA0` and `xB0, vB0` of spaceships A and B respectively. As you said, B moves with no acceleration and with constant velocity `vB0`. Therefore, it travels uniformly along a straight line. Its motion is described as: `xB = xB0 + t*vB0`. Spaceship A can turn on and off an acceleration of constant magnitude `a0` but can change its direction as it sees fit. The velocity of A should not exceed certain value `v_max > 0`.

Since spaceship B travels uniformly, along a straight line with constant velocity `vB0`, it actually defines an inertial coordinate system. In other words, if we translate the original coordinate system and attach it to B, the new system travels with constant velocity along a straight line and is therefore also inertial. The transformation is Galilean, so one can define the following change of coordinates (in both directions)

```matlab
y = x - xB0 - t*vB0
u = v - vB0

x = y + xB0 + t*vB0
v = u + vB0
```

in particular, for B for any moment of time `t` we get

```matlab
yB = xB - xB0 - t*vB0 = xB0 + t*vB0 - xB0 - t*vB0  = 0``
```

At time `t=0`,

```matlab
yA0 = xA0 - xB0  

uA0 = vA0 - vB0
```

We are aiming to design the control in this new coordinate system and them move it back into the original one. So let us switch coordinates:

```matlab
y = x - xB
u = v - vB0
```

So in this new inertial coordinate system we are solving a problem of control theory and to engineer a good control, we would use as a Lyapunov function (a function that allows us to guarantee certain stable behavior and design the proper expression for the acceleration `a`) the magnitude of the velocity squared `L = norm(u)^2`. We want to design acceleration `a` so that the Lyapunov function in the initial phase of the motion monotonically and steadily decreases while the velocity reorients appropriately.

Define the unit vector

```matlab
L_unit = cross(x0A - xB0, v0A - vB0) / norm(cross(x0A - xB0, v0A - vB0))
```

Let in the coordinate system attached to B the motion of A satisfy the system of ordinary differential equations (these equations in both systems are Newton's, because both systems are inertial):

```matlab
dy/dt = u

du/dt = - a0 * (u - cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u - cross(L_unit, u))
```

In other words, the acceleration is set to

```matlab
a = - a0 * (u - cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u - cross(L_unit, u))
```

Observe that by design `norm(a) = a0`. Because the vectors `u` and `cross(L_unit, u)` are orthogonal and of equal magnitude (simply `cross(L_unit, u)` is the ninety degree rotation of vector `u`), the denominator simplifies to

```matlab
norm(u - cross(L_unit, u)) = sqrt( norm(u - cross(L_unit, u))^2 ) 
                           = sqrt( norm(u)^2 + norm(L_unit, u)^2 )
                           = sqrt( norm(u)^2 + norm(L_unit)^2*norm(u)^2 )
                           = sqrt( norm(u)^2 + norm(u)^2)
                           = sqrt(2) * norm(u)
```

So the system of differential equations simplifies to

```matlab
dy/dt = u

du/dt = -(a0/sqrt(2)) * u/norm(u) + (a0/sqrt(2)) * cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u)
```

The system is designed so that A always moves in the plane passing thorugh the origin B and perpendicular to the vector `L_unit`.

Because`u` and `cross(L_unit, u)` are perpendicular, their dot product is 0, which allows us to calculate the time-derivative of the lyapunov function along the solutions to the system above (`u'` means transpose of column-vector `u`):

```matlab
d/dt( L ) = d/dt( norm(u)^2 ) = d/dt( u' * u ) = u' * du/dt 
          = u' * (  -(a0/sqrt(2)) * u/norm(u) 
            + (a0/sqrt(2)) * cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u) )
          = -(a0/sqrt(2)) * u'*u / norm(u) 
            + (a0/sqrt(2)) * u'*cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u) 
          = -(a0/sqrt(2)) * norm(u)^2 / norm(u)
          = -(a0/sqrt(2)) * norm(u)
          = - (a0/sqrt(2)) * sqrt(L)

d/dt( L ) = -(a0/sqrt(2)) * sqrt(L) < 0
```

which means that `norm(u)` decreases with time to 0, as desired.

The system of differential equations, that governs the motion, looks initially non-linear but can be linearized and explicitly solvaed. However, for simplicity, I have decided to integrate it numerically.

The system of differential equations, that governs the motion, looks initially non-linear but can be linearized and explicitly solved. However, for simplicity, I have decided to integrate it numerically. To do that, I have chosen a geometric integrator method, where the system is split into two explicitly solvable systems, whose solutions are combined together to give (a very good approximation of) the solution to the original system. The systems are:

```matlab
dy/dt = u / 2

du/dt = -(a0/sqrt(2)) u / norm(u)
```

and

```matlab
dy/dt = u / 2

du/dt = (a0/sqrt(2)) cross(L_unit, u) / norm(u)
```

Initially, the second system is nonlinear, however after we calculate:

```matlab
d/dt(norm(u)*2) = d/dt (dot(u, u)) = 2 * dot(u, du/dt) 
                = 2 * dot(u, (a0/sqrt(2)) * cross(L_unit , u))
                = 2 * (a0/sqrt(2)) * dot(u, cross(L_unit , u)) 
                = 0
```

we conclude that during the motion defined by this system, the magnitude of the
velocity is constant, i.e. `norm(u) = norm(u0)` where `u0 = u(0)`. Thus, the systems, together with their solutions, now look like:

```matlab
First system:

dy/dt = u / 2

du/dt = -(a0/sqrt(2)) u / norm(u)

Solution:
y(t) = y0  +  h * u0/2  -  t^2 * a0 * u0 / (4*sqrt(2)*norm(u0));
u(t) = u - t * a0 * u0 / (sqrt(2)*norm(u0));
```

and

```matlab
Second system:

dy/dt = u / 2

du/dt = (a0/(sqrt(2)*norm(u0))) cross(L_unit, u) 

Solution:
y(t) = y0 + (sqrt(2)*norm(u0)/a0) *( cross(L_unit, u0)
          + sin( t * a0/(sqrt(2)*norm(u0)) ) * u0  
          - cos( t  *a0/(sqrt(2)*norm(u0)) ) * cross(L_unit, u0) )     
u(t) = cos( t  *a0/(sqrt(2)*norm(u0)) ) * u0  
       + sin( t  *a0/(sqrt(2)*norm(u0)) ) * cross(L_unit, u0)
```

The solution to the original system can be approximated as follows. Select a time step `h`. Then if at time `t` the spaceship's position and velocity have been calculated to be `y, u`, the updated spaceship's position and velocity at time `t + h` can be calculated by first letting the ship move along the solution of the second system starting from `y, u` for time `h/2`, then move along the solution of the first system for time `h` and then move along the solution of the second system for time `h/2`.

```matlab
function main()
    h = 0.3;
    a0 = 0.1;
    u_max = .8; % velocity threshold
    xB0 = [0; 0; 0];
    vB0 = [-1; 2; 0];
    xA0 = [ 7; 12; 0] + xB0;
    vA0 = [1; 5; 0]/7;
    %vA0 =  [2; -1; 0];
    L_unit = cross(xA0 - xB0, vA0 - vB0);
    L_unit =  L_unit / norm(L_unit);
    t = 0;
    xB = xB0;
    x = xA0;
    v = vA0;
    hold on
    grid on
    %axis([-200 20 -100 350])
    plot(0, 0, 'bo')

    % STEP 0 (the motion as described in the text above):
    n = floor(sqrt(2)*norm(vA0 - vB0)/(a0*h));
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = E(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    u = v - vB0;
    norm_u = norm(u);
    % short additional decceleration so that A attains velocity v = vB0 
    t0 = t + norm_u/a0;    
    n = floor((t0 - t)/h); 
    a = - a0 * u / norm_u;    
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t0-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
    
    % STEP 1 (uniform acceleration of magnitude a0):
    v = vB0; 
    a = x-xB;
    norm_y0 = norm(a);
    a = - a0 * a / norm_y0;
    %t2 = t1 + sqrt( norm_y/a0 ); 
    accel_time = min( u_max/a0, sqrt( norm_y0/a0 ) );
    t1 = t0 + accel_time;
    n = floor((t1 - t0)/h);     
    for i=1:n
       [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
       plot(x(1), x(2), 'bo');
       plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'ro');
       pause(0.1)
    end 
    [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t1-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'bo');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'ro');
    pause(0.1)
    
    % STEP 2 (uniform straight-line motion): 
    norm_y1 = norm(x-xB);
    norm_y12 = max(0, norm_y0 - 2*(norm_y0 - norm_y1));
    t12 = norm_y12 / norm(v-vB0)
    t = t + t12
    n12 = floor(t12/h)
    for i=1:n12
        x = x + h*v; 
        xB = xB + h*vB0;
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    x = x + (t12-n12*h)*v; 
    xB = xB + (t12-n12*h)*vB0;
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)

    % STEP 3 (uniform deceleration of magnitude a0, symmetric to STEP 1): 
    a = -a;
    for i=1:n % t2 + (t2-t1)
       [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
       plot(x(1), x(2), 'bo');
       plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'ro');
       pause(0.1)
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t0+t12+2*accel_time-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'bo');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'ro');
    pause(0.1)
    norm(x-xB)
    norm(v-vB0)
end
```

Here are the additional functions that are used in the main code above:

```matlab
% change of coordinates from world coordinates x, v 
% to coordinates y, u from spaship B's point of view:
function [y, u] = change(x, v, xB, vB0)
    y = x - xB;
    u = v - vB0;
end

% inverse chage of coordinates from y, u to x, v
function [x, v] = inv_change(y, u, xB, vB0)
    x = y + xB;
    v = u + vB0;
end

% solution to the second system of differential equations for a step h:
function [y_out, u_out] = R(y, u, a0, L_unit, h)
   omega = a0 / (sqrt(2) * norm(u));
   L_x_u = cross(L_unit, u);
   cos_omega_h = cos(omega*h);
   sin_omega_h = sin(omega*h);
   omega = 2*omega;
   y_out = y + (L_x_u ...
       + sin_omega_h * u  -  cos_omega_h * L_x_u) / omega;      
   u_out = cos_omega_h * u  +  sin_omega_h * L_x_u;
end

% solution to the first system of differential equations for a step h:
function [y_out, u_out] = T(y, u, a0, h)
    sqrt_2 = sqrt(2);
    u_unit = u / norm(u);  
    y_out = y  +  h * u/2  -  h^2 * a0 * u_unit/ (4*sqrt_2);
    u_out = u - h * a0 * u_unit / sqrt_2;
end

% approximate solution of the original system of differential equations for step h
% i.e. the sum of furst and second systems of differential equations:
function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = E(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, h)
   t_out = t + h;
   [y, u] = change(x, v, xB, vB0);
   [y, u] = R(y, u, a0, L_unit, h/2);
   [y, u] = T(y, u, a0, h);
   [y, u] = R(y, u, a0, L_unit, h/2);
   xB_out = xB + h*vB0;
   [x_out, v_out] = inv_change(y, u, xB_out, vB0);  
end

% straight-line motion with constant acceleration: 
function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = ET(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h)
    t_out = t + h;
    [y, u] = change(x, v, xB, vB0);
    y = y  +  h * u  +  h^2 * a / 2;
    u = u + h * a;
    xB_out = xB + h*vB0;
    [x_out, v_out] = inv_change(y, u, xB_out, vB0);
end
```

**OLDER VERSION:**

I developed two models. Both models are initially described in the moving with B inertial frame of reference `y, u` (see my previous answers) and then the coordinates are transformed into the original ones `x, v`. I designed the control based on the function `norm(u)^2` as a Lyapunov function, so that in the first step of the algorithm, the acceleration is designed so that the Lyapunov function `norm(u)^2` decreases steadily. In the first version, the speed of decrease is quadratic, but the model is easier to integrate, while in the second version, the speed of decrease is exponential, but the model requires Runge-Kutta integration. And I haven't quite tuned it well. I think Version 1 should looks good.

Take `L_unit = cross(y0, u0) / norm(cross(y0, u0))`.

**Version 1:** The model is:

```
dy/dt = y
du/dt = - a0 * (u + cross(L_unit, u)) / norm(u + cross(L_unit, u))
      = - a0 * (u + cross(L_unit, u)) / (norm(u)*sqrt(1 + norm(L_unit)^2))
      = - a0 * (u + cross(L_unit, u)) / (sqrt(2) * norm(u))
```

To integrate it, split it into a pair of systems:

```
dy/dt = y
du/dt = - a0 * u / norm(u)

dy/dt = y
du/dt = - a0 * cross(L_unit, u) / norm(u0)  (see previous answers)
```

and integrate them one after the other for small increments of `h` time intervals, and then go back and forth between these two systems consecutively. I experimented with some Matlab code:

```matlab
function main()
    h = 0.3;
    a0 = 0.1;
    xB0 = [0; 0; 0];
    vB0 = [-1; 2; 0];
    xA0 = [ 7; 12; 0] + xB0;
    vA0 =  [2; -1; 0];
    L_unit = cross(xA0 - xB0, vA0 - vB0);
    L_unit =  L_unit / norm(L_unit);
    t = 0;
    xB = xB0;
    x = xA0;
    v = vA0;
    hold on
    grid on
    %axis([-200 20 -100 350])
    plot(0, 0, 'bo')
    n = floor(2*norm(v - vB0)/(h*a0));
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = R(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, h/2);
        a = - a0 * (v - vB0) / norm(v - vB0);
        [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h/2);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    t1 = t + norm(v - vB0)/a0;
    n = floor((t1 - t)/h); 
    a = - a0 * (v - vB0) / norm(v - vB0);
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t1-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
    t2 = t1 + sqrt( norm(x - xB)/a0 ); 
    n = floor((t2 - t1)/h);
    a = - a0 * (x - xB) / norm(x - xB);
    v = vB0;
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1) 
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t2-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
    for i=1:n % t2 + (t2-t1)
       [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, -a, h);
       plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
       plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
       pause(0.1) 
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, -a, 2*t2 - t1 -t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
end
```

where the relevant functions are:

```matlab
function [t_out, y_out, u_out] = R1(t, y, u, a0, L_unit, h)
   t_out = t + h;
   norm_u = norm(u);
   R = norm_u^2 / a0;
   cos_omega_h = cos(a0 * h / norm_u);
   sin_omega_h = sin(a0 * h / norm_u);
   u_unit = u / norm_u;
   y_out = y + R * cross(L_unit, u_unit) ...
           + R * sin_omega_h * u_unit ...
           - R * cos_omega_h * cross(L_unit, u_unit);
   u_out = norm_u * sin_omega_h * cross(L_unit, u_unit) ...
           + norm_u * cos_omega_h * u_unit;
end

function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = R(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, h)
    [t_out, y_out, u_out] = R1(t, x - xB, v - vB0, a0, L_unit, h);
    xB_out = xB + h * vB0;
    x_out = y_out + xB_out;
    v_out = u_out + vB0;
end

function [t_out, y_out, u_out] = T1(t, y, u, a, h)
    t_out = t + h;
    u_out = u + h * a;
    y_out = y + h * u + h^2 * a / 2; 
end

function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h)
    [t_out, y_out, u_out] = T1(t, x - xB, v - vB0, a, h);
    xB_out = xB + h * vB0;
    x_out = y_out + xB_out;
    v_out = u_out + vB0;
end
```

**Version 2:** The model is:

```
0 < k0 < 2 * a0 / norm(u0)  

dy/dt = y
du/dt = - k0 * u / 2 + sqrt(a0^2 - k0^2 * norm_u^2 / 4) * cross(L_unit, u/norm_u);
```

Matlab code:

```matlab
function main()
    h = 0.3;
    a0 = 0.1;
    xB0 = [0; 0; 0];
    vB0 = [-1; 2; 0];
    xA0 = [ 7; 12; 0] + xB0;
    vA0 =  [2; -1; 0];
    k0 = a0/norm(vA0-vB0);
    L_unit = cross(xA0 - xB0, vA0 - vB0);
    L_unit =  L_unit / norm(L_unit);
    t = 0;
    xB = xB0;
    x = xA0;
    v = vA0;
    hold on
    grid on
    %axis([-200 20 -100 350])
    plot(0, 0, 'bo')
    n = floor(2*norm(v - vB0)/(h*a0)); % this needs to be improved 
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = F_step(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, k0, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    t1 = t + norm(v - vB0)/a0;
    n = floor((t1 - t)/h); 
    a = - a0 * (v - vB0) / norm(v - vB0);
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1)
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t1-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
    t2 = t1 + sqrt( norm(x - xB)/a0 ); 
    n = floor((t2 - t1)/h);
    a = - a0 * (x - xB) / norm(x - xB);
    v = vB0;
    for i=1:n
        [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h);
        plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
        plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
        pause(0.1) 
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, t2-t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
    for i=1:n % t2 + (t2-t1)
       [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, -a, h);
       plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
       plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
       pause(0.1) 
    end
    [t, x, v, xB] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, -a, 2*t2 - t1 -t);
    plot(x(1), x(2), 'ro');
    plot(xB(1), xB(2), 'bo');
    pause(0.1)
end
```

where the relevant functions are:

```matlab
function [dydt, dudt] = F1(u, a0, L_unit, k0)
    norm_u = norm(u);
    dydt = u;
    dudt = - k0 * u / 2 + sqrt(a0^2 - k0^2 * norm_u^2/4) * cross(L_unit, u/norm_u);
end

function [t_out, y_out, u_out] = F1_step(t, y, u, a0, L_unit, k0, h)
    t_out = t + h;
    [z1, w1] = F1(u, a0, L_unit, k0);
    [z2, w2] = F1(u + h * w1/2, a0, L_unit, k0);
    [z3, w3] = F1(u + h * w2/2, a0, L_unit, k0);
    [z4, w4] = F1(u + h * w3, a0, L_unit, k0);
    y_out = y + h*(z1 + 2*z2 + 2*z3 + z4)/6;
    u_out = u + h*(w1 + 2*w2 + 2*w3 + w4)/6;
end

function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = F_step(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a0, L_unit, k0, h)
    [t_out, x_out, v_out] = F1_step(t, x-xB, v-vB0, a0, L_unit, k0, h);
    xB_out = xB + h * vB0;
    x_out = x_out + xB_out;
    v_out = v_out + vB0;
end

function [t_out, y_out, u_out] = T1(t, y, u, a, h)
    t_out = t + h;
    u_out = u + h * a;
    y_out = y + h * u + h^2 * a / 2; 
end

function [t_out, x_out, v_out, xB_out] = T(t, x, v, xB, vB0, a, h)
    [t_out, y_out, u_out] = T1(t, x - xB, v - vB0, a, h);
    xB_out = xB + h * vB0;
    x_out = y_out + xB_out;
    v_out = u_out + vB0;
end
```

Comment: You have been very helpful! It's going to take me a little while to digest and try an implementation of your solution, alas, my math skills are lacking and I know nothing at all about Matlab syntax. But I'm sure I can figure it out with a little bit of effort. I'll mark your solution as an answer and I will report back when I have had the time to try it.

Comment: @LordVinkel Thank you for your question, it was interesting to work on it. I added a new version of an algorithm with more systematic theoretical background. Everything is better justified and designed based on more careful application of  dynamical systems and control methodology. I am sorry for the Matlab code, but I do not know java or javascript languages. Plus, matlab is very intuitive and explicit in its syntax. You can just read it as pseudocode and ask if you have difficulty understanding.

Comment: Curious if anyone has got this to work. I think I managed to faithfully translate this from MATLAB to Java, but my numbers careen off into the stratosphere very quickly (by the 5th iteration of Step 0, x is off in the 1e18 range, and eventually "Infinity"s out).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be in the R function, where y_out is calculated. It divides by omega, but omega is always quite small. R is called twice in E, so y_out gains several orders of magnitude each iteration without bound.

Comment: @WillHartung Why is omega always small? Is the magnitude a0 of the acceleration that you are using almost zero, or is a0 very small relative to a very large magnitude of initial relative velocity vA(0) - vB(0) between the two ships? When I wrote this and tested it, it worked fine, with reasonable initial input parameters a0 vA(0) and vB(0). Are you implementing the scripts from the new version of the post?

Comment: @Futurologist I'm implementing the version at the top of this post (I assume its the correct one). a0 starts at 0.1, and the other values are set from the constants. vA0 is set to [1; 5; 0]/7. In R(), my first time through, u (after change()) is [1.14, -1.28, 0], and u norm (I use length) is 1.71. So, Omega is .1 / 2.424, which is about 0.04. And away it goes after that.

Comment: @WillHartung  I implemented this in python and I am not seeing any problems. a0 is constant, never changes. the function R() seems to work fine. In fact, R() should be simple rotation along the axis L_unit where omega is the angular velocity of this rotation, getting multiplied by the time step h.

Comment: @Futurologist When I enter R for the first time, I have y=[7,12,0], u=[1.14,-1.28,0], a0=.1,L_unit=[0,0,-1],h=.15. Omega computes to 0.04. Do those parameters look right to you? MATLABs norm(u) is the same as |u|, correct? Magnitude of the vector?

Comment: @WillHartung Yes, all of the above are correct. Nothing blows up.

Comment: @Futurologist So, an omega of .04 is ok? Because we divide by omega, which makes the, inevitably, x vector continually larger. I have a gist https://gist.github.com/willhartung/c1e888f63039d367a5f934b192fa4849 which shows the values being sent to R in Step 0, as well as my R source code. This all looks fine to me, save the values. Are these the values you are seeing?

Comment: @WillHartung The omega is absolutely fine. 0.04 is not a small number. c does not get larger as fast as you think. And, no, I have completely different output numbers. You may have translated the formulas incorrectly from matlab to java. Also u and u_out should have the same magnitude. Yours do not seem to match. Most likely your function does not calculate the vector transformation from u to u_out correctly.

Comment: @WillHartung Your error is probably this one: `u.multiply(cos_omega_h).add(L_x_u.multiply(cos_omega_h));` It should be `u.multiply(cos_omega_h).add(L_x_u.multiply(sin_omega_h));`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to outline a somewhat simple approach, back of the envelope so to say, divided into four simple steps.

Assume you have the initial positions and velocities`xA0,  vA0` and `xB0, vB0` of spaceship A and B respectively. As you said, B moves with no acceleration and with constant velocity `vB0`. Therefore, it travels uniformly along a straight line. Its motion is described as:
`xB = xB0 + t*vB0` 
Spaceship A can turn on and off an acceleration of constant magnitude `a0` but can change its direction as it sees fit.

I really hope that your velocitiy limit satisfies `norm(vA0 - vB0) < v_max` otherwise, the acceleration control you have to construct becomes more complex.

**Step 1:** Kill the difference between the velocities of A and B. Apply constant acceleration

```
a = a0 *(vB0 - vA0) / norm(vB0 - vA0)
```

to spaceship A. Then, the positions and the velocities of A and B change with time as follows:

```
xA = xA0 + t*vA0 + t^2*a0*(vB0 - vA0)/(2*norm(vB0 - vA0))
vA = vA0 + t*a0*(vB0 - vA0)/norm(vB0 - vA0)
xB = xB0 + t*vB0
vB = vB0
```

At time `t1 = norm(vB0 - vA0)/a0` the velocity of spaceship A is `vB0` which is equal in magnitude and direction to the velocity of spaceship B. At `t1` if A turns off its acceleration and keeps it off, it will travel parallel to B, just with an offset in space.

**Explanation:** (not needed for the algorithm, but explains the calculations used in the next steps)
Since spaceship B travels uniformly, along a straight line with constant velocity vB0, it actually defines an inertial coordinate system. In other words, if we translate the original coordinate system and attach it to B, the new system travels with constant velocity along a straight line and is therefore also inertial. The transformation is Galilean, so one can define the following change of coordinates (in both directions)

```
y = x - xB0 - t*vB0
u = v - vB0

x = y + xB0 + t*vB0
v = u + vB0
```

At time `t1` from step 1, the positions of the two spaceships are

```
xA1 = xA0 + t1*vA0 + t1^2*a0*(vB0 - vA0)/(2*norm(vB0 - vA0))
xB1 = xB0 + t*vB0
```

and their velocities are `vA1 = vB1 = vB0`. Thus

```
yA1 = xA1 - xB0 - t1*vB0  

yB1 = xB1 - xB0 - t1*vB0 = xB0 + t1*vB0 - xB0 - t1*vB0  = 0
```

In this coordinate system, if at time `t1` A turns off its acceleration and keeps it off, it will be just stationary, i.e. its position `yA1` will not change with time. Now, all we have to do is move A from point `yA1` to `0` along the straight-line segment `AB`, defined by the vector `- yA1 = vector(AB)` (pointing from A to the origin B). The idea is that now A can simply move with constant acceleration along `AB` for some time `(t2-t1)`, gaining some velocity `uA2` which does not exceed your velocity limit `morm(uA2 + vB0) < v_max`, then turn off the acceleration and fly for some period of time `(t3-t2)`, which is to be determined, with velocity `uA2`, and finally turn on decceleration along `AB` for time `(t4-t3) = (t2-t1)`, and at time `t4` the A and B meet and the velocity of A is 0 (in the new coordinate system, the one flying with B). Which means the two ships are at the same location and have the same velocity (as a vector) in the original coordinate system.

Now,

```
yA = yA1 - (t-t1)^2*a0*yA1/(2*norm(yA1))
uA = (t-t1)*a0*yA1/norm(yA1)
```

so at `t2` (all points `yA1, yA2, yA3` and `0` are collinear):

```
yA2 = yA1 - (t2-t1)^2*a0*yA1/(2*norm(yA1)) = (norm(yA1)-(t2-t1)^2*a0/(2*norm(yA1))) * yA1
uA2 = (t2-t1)*a0*yA1/norm(yA1)

norm(yA2 - yA1) = norm( yA1 - (t2-t1)^2*a0*yA1/(2*norm(yA1)) - yA1 ) 
                = norm(- (t2-t1)^2*a0*yA1/(2*norm(yA1))) 
                = (t2-t1)^2*(a0/2)*norm(yA1/norm(yA1))
                = (t2-t1)^2*a0/2
norm(yA1) = norm(yA2 - yA1) + norm(yA3 - yA2) + norm(0 - yA3)

norm(yA3 - yA2) = norm(yA1) - norm(yA2 - yA1) - norm(0 - yA3) 
                =  norm(yA1) - (t2-t1)^2*a0

(t3-t2) = norm(yA3 - yA2) / norm(uA2) = ( norm(yA1) - (t2-t1)^2*a0 )/norm(uA2)
```

Now, let us return to the original coordinate system.

```
yA1 = xA1 - xB1
uA2 = vA2 - vB0 
(t3-t2) = ( norm(xA1 - xB1) - (t2-t1)^2*a0 )/norm(vA2 - vB0)
```

so the important calculation here is: as soon as you choose your `t2`, you get to calculate

```
t3 = t2 + ( norm(xA1 - xB1) - (t2-t1)^2*a0 )/norm(vA2 - vB0)
```

**Step 2:** As it was mentioned already, at time `t1` from step 1, the positions of the two spaceships are

```
xA1 = xA0 + t1*vA0 + t1^2*a0*(vB0 - vA0)/(2*norm(vB0 - vA0))
xB1 = xB0 + t*vB0
```

and their velocities are `vA1 = vB1 = vB0`.

At time `t1` apply acceleration `a = a0*(xB1 - xA1)/norm(xB1 - xA1)`. Then, the positions and the velocities of A and B change with time as follows:

```
xA = xA1 + (t-t1)*vB0 + (t-t1)^2*a0*(xB1 - xA1)/(2*norm(xB1 - xA1))
vA = vB0 + (t-t1)*a0*(xB1 - xA1)/norm(xB1 - xA1)
xB = xB1 + (t-t1)*vB0 or if you prefer xB = xB0 + t*vB0
vB = vB0
```

Pick any `t2` that satisfies

```
t2 <= t1 + sqrt( norm(xA1 - xB1)/a0 )   (the time to get to the middle of ``AB`` accelerating)

and such that it satisfies

norm( vB0 - (t2 - t1)*a0*(xA1 - xB1)/norm(xA1 - xB1) ) < v_max
```

Then at time `t2` you get the positions an velocities

```
xA2 = xA1 + (t2-t1)*vB0 + (t2-t1)^2*a0*(xB1 - xA1)/(2*norm(xB1 - xA1))
vA2 = vB0 + (t2-t1)*a0*(xB1 - xA1)/norm(xB1 - xA1)
xB2 = xB1 + (t2-t1)*vB0   or if you prefer xB2 = xB0 + t2*vB0
vB2 = vB0
```

**Step 3:** Calculate the next time-moment

```
t3 = t2 + ( norm(xA1 - xB1) - (t2-t1)^2*a0 )/norm(vA2 - vB0)
```

and since A moves with constant velocity `vA2` along a straight line:

```
xA3 = xA2 + (t3-t2)*vA2
vA3 = vA2
xB3 = xB2 + (t3-t2)*vB0   or if you prefer xB3 = xB0 + t3*vB0
vB3 = vB0
```

**Step 4:** This is the final stretch, when A deccelerates to meet with B:

```
t4 = t3 + (t2-t1)
```

At time `t3` apply acceleration `a = a0*(xA1 - xB1)/norm(xA1 - XB1)`, exactly opposite to the one from step 2. Then, the positions and the velocities of A and B change with time as follows:

```
xA = xA3 + (t-t3)*vB3 + (t-t3)^2*a0*(xA1 - xB1)/(2*norm(xA1 - xB1))
vA = vB3 + (t-t3)*a0*(xA1 - xB1)/norm(xA1 - xB1)
xB = xB3 + (t-t3)*vB0 or if you prefer xB = xB0 + t*vB0
vB = vB0
```

and for `t4` we should have

```
xA4 = xB4  and vA4 = vB0
```

Now I realize there is a fair amount of details, so it possible I have some typos and possibly errors. However, the idea looks sound to me but I advise you to redo some of the calculations, just to be sure.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you suggest that I first equalize the velocities of the spaceships and then move spaceship A towards B. I have tried this already, and it does indeed work, however the problem is that it doesn't look right. Depending on the initial positions and velocities it can cause spaceship A to first move one way and then move back the same way. This satisfies the need to equalize position and velocity but is more inefficient than I would like, and it also makes the movement look weird.

Thus, what I am hoping for is a solution to how to merge the two first steps.

Comment: @LordVinkel Ok, so moving of spaceship A one way and then the other happens when the velocities of A and B point in opposite directions. Is your model in two or three dimensions?

Comment: Depending on velocity and relative position, the method of doing one after another means sometimes the spaceship will have to burn in one direction first to match velocities, and then burn in the opposite direction to match position. It works, but it looks strange and is inefficient. I use three dimensions, but I use vectors so there shouldn't be any difference if i only used two.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the initial positions and velocities `xA0, vA0` and `xB0, vB0` of spaceships A and B respectively. As you said, B moves with no acceleration and with constant velocity `vB0`. Therefore, it travels uniformly along a straight line. Its motion is described as: `xB = xB0 + t*vB0`. Spaceship A can turn on and off an acceleration of constant magnitude `a0` but can change its direction as it sees fit.

Since spaceship B travels uniformly, along a straight line with constant velocity `vB0`, it actually defines an inertial coordinate system. In other words, if we translate the original coordinate system and attach it to B, the new system travels with constant velocity along a straight line and is therefore also inertial. The transformation is Galilean, so one can define the following change of coordinates (in both directions)

```
y = x - xB0 - t*vB0
u = v - vB0

x = y + xB0 + t*vB0
v = u + vB0
```

in particular, for B for any moment of time `t` we get

```
yB = xB - xB0 - t*vB0 = xB0 + t*vB0 - xB0 - t*vB0  = 0``
```

At time `t=0`,

```
yA0 = xA0 - xB0  

uA0 = vA0 - vB0
```

So we are going to design the control in this new coordinate system and them move it back into the original one. First, spaceship A is going move so that its velocity has always the same magnitude `norm(uA) = norm(uA0)` but its direction changes uniformly. To achieve that, one can simply take the cross-product vector

```
L0 = cross(yA0, uA0) / ( norm( cross(yA0, uA0) ) * norm(uA0) )
```

and at each moment of time `t` apply acceleration

```
a = a0 * cross(L0, uA)
```

This means that the law of motion of A satisfies the differential equations

```
dyA/dt = uA

duA/dt = a0 * cross(L0 , uA)
```

then

```
d/dt (dot(uA, uA)) = 2 * dot(uA, duA/dt) = 2 * dot(uA, a0 * cross(L0 , uA))
                  = 2 * a0 * dot(uA, cross(L0 , uA)) 
                  = 0
```

which is possible only when `norm(uA)^2 = dot(uA, uA) = norm(uA0)`, i.e. the magnitude `norm(uA) = norm(uA0)` for all `t` is constant.

Let us check the norm of the acceleration's magnitude:

```
norm(a) = a0 * norm( cross(L0, uA)) = a0 * norm(L0) * norm(uA)
        = a0 * norm( cross(yA0, uA0)/( norm( cross(yA0, uA0) )*norm(uA0) ) )*norm(uA0)
        = a0 * norm( cross(yA0, uA0) )/( norm( cross(yA0, uA0) )*norm(uA0) ) )*norm(uA0) 
        = a0
```

Since `norm(uA) = norm(uA0) = const` the tip of the velocity of A, drawn as a vector `uA` from the origin B, always lies on the sphere `norm(uA) = norm(uA0)` centered at the origin. At the same time

```
d/dt ( dot(L0, uA) ) = dot(L0, duA/dt) = a0 * dot(L0, cross(L0, uA)) = 0
which means that
dot(L0, uA) = const = dot(L0, uA0) = 0
```

hence `uA` always lies on a plane perpendicular to vector `L0` and passing through the origin. Thus, `uA` points to the intersection of the said plane with the sphere `norm(uA) = norm(uA0)`, i.e. `uA` traverses a circle. In other words, the equation

```
duA/dt = a0 cross(L0, uA)
```

defines a rotation around the origin of vector `uA` in a plane through the origin and perpendicular to `L0`. Next, take

```
dyA/dt - a0*cross(L0, yA) = uA - a0*cross(L0, yA)
```

and differentiate it with respect to t:

```
duA/dt - a0*cross(L0, dyA/dt) = duA/dt - a0*cross(L0, uA) = 0
```

which means that there exists a constant vector such that `dyA/dt - a0*cross(L0, yA) = const_vect` and we can rewrite this last equation as

```
dyA/dt = a0*cross(L0, yA - cA)

and even like

d/dt( yA - cA ) = a0*cross(L0, yA - cA)
```

which just by the same arguments as the ones for `uA` implies that `yA - cA` traverses a circle centered at the origin and in a plane perpendicular to `L0`. Consequently, `yA` traverses a circle in the plane through the origin, perpendicular to `L0` and centered at `cA`. One just needs to find the radius and the center of the circle. Then the motion of A under the equations

```
dyA/dt = uA

duA/dt = a0* cross(L0, uA)
```

reduces to the equation

```
dyA/dt = a0 * cross(L0, yA - cA)

yA(0) = yA0
```

In order to find the radius `R`, we set time `t=0`:

```
uA0 = a0 * cross(L0, yA0 - cA)
so
norm(uA0) = a0 * norm(cross(L0, yA0 - cA)) = a0 * norm(L0) * norm(yA0 - cA)
          = a0 * norm(L0) * R
norm(L0) = 1 / norm(uA0)

R = norm(uA0)^2 / a0
```

The center is then along the vector perpendicular to both `uA0` and `L0` , so

```
cA = yA0 + R * cross(L0, uA0) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))
```

Then, we can set up a 2D coordinate system in the plane in which the motion occurs by choosing origin `yA0` and unit perpendicular vectors `uA0/norm(uA0)` and `-cross(L0, uA0) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))`. So the motion of A in the coordinate system moving uniformly in a straight line with B can be described as

```
yA(t) = yA0  + R * sin(a0 * t / norm(L0)) * uA0 / norm(uA0)
             - R * cos(a0 * t / norm(L0)) * cross(L0, uA0) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))
```

which is the solution to the initial value problem:

```
dyA/dt = uA0

duA/dt = a0 * cross(L0, uA)

yA(0) = yA0
uA(0) = uA0
```

So my new suggestion is to incorporate

**Step 0:** For a time period `t` from `0` to `t0` apply the following acceleration and motion, which rotates the direction of the velocity vector of A:

```
yA0 = xA0 - xB0
uA0 = vA0 - vB0
L0 = cross(yA0, uA0) / ( norm( cross(yA0, uA0) ) * norm(uA0) )
a = a0 * cross(L0, uA0)
R = norm(uA0)^2 / a0

yA(t) = yA0 + R * cos(a0*t/norm(uA0)) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))
            + R * sin(a0*t/norm(uA0)) * uA0/norm(uA0)
            - R * cos(a0*t/norm(uA0)) * cross(L0, uA0) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))

xA(t) = yA(t) + xB0 + t * vB0 = 
      = xA0 + t * vB0 + R * cos(a0*t/norm(uA0)) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))
            + R * sin(a0*t/norm(uA0)) * uA0/norm(uA0)
            - R * cos(a0*t/norm(uA0)) * cross(L0, uA0) / (norm(L0)*norm(uA0))
```

until a moment of time `t0` chosen so that the velocity's direction `vA(t)` is at a better position relative to `vB0` so that from moment `t0` on, you can apply the four steps outlined in my previous answer. Of course you can also use this new circular motion control to make your own combination that you like better.